# Why does/would Symfony 3 Require (entity name).orm.xml when annotations are used?

Tags: symfony

Error:
No mapping file found named 'MyEntity.orm.xml' for class 'AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity'.

Note: there is ONE existing orm.xml file in the resources/config/doctrine directory that is for the FOSUser Bundle.

Controller:

```
namespace TduLookupBundle\Controller;


use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;
use ConsumptionBundle\Form\CompleteInputsFormType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use TduLookupBundle\Form\ZipcodeFormType;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/select_by_myentity", name="select_by_myentity")
     */
    public function doSomethingAction(Request $request)
    {
        $MyEntityRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:MyEntity');

        dump($MyEntityRepository);
        die();

    }

}
```

Entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_unique_state_name", columns={"state_name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
 */
class MyEntity
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state_name", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $stateName;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;



    public function __toString()
    {
        $str = self::getStateName();
        return $str;
    }


    /**
     * Get stateName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStateName()
    {
        return $this->stateName;
    }


    /**
     * Set stateName
     *
     * @param string $stateName
     *
     * @return GeoState
     */
    public function setStateName($stateName)
    {
        $this->stateName = $stateName;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which folder did you create the Entity file `MyEntity`? Also, I don't see a namespace at the top...

Comment: Entity with Annotations is in AppBundle\Entity folder.

I have just created a new Bundle called PDUserBundle and moved the FOSUser and associated components therein and now I can access the repositories in a traditional manner.

Still, the question, Why?  

Maybe Why can't part of the defined entities be orm.xml files and why can't some be annotation as long as there is not an overlap?

Comment: I'm confused. Also in your post, you say you have a "orm.xml" file in `resources/config/doctrine` folder. Did you create that folder and that file? Also is this Symfony2 or Symfony3? They are quite different.

Comment: Symfony 3 and I added it per the FOSUserBundle instructions here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Comment: I see you've selected the `XML` tab of that web page. Normally you would create the file `src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php` as shown in the `Annotations` tab. The PHP file is simpler to create and understand.

Comment: Could you please post the doctrine part of your config.yml file?

Comment: Alvin and Romi, I will have to come back to this later, but I have a family emergency and will be out for a week at least.  Thanks for your help and I will circle back to this ASAP.